# curious css setting issue using setInterval

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to make a palindrome checker that changes the currently compared letters as it recurs.

[image]

Essentially, `callback` will do:

- **r** aceca **r**
- r **a** cec **a** r
- ra **c** e **c** ar
- rac **e** car

My [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/huqudolu/13/) shows that the compared letters change green sometimes, but if you run it again, the letters won't change. Why is there a difference in results? It seems to sometimes run in Chrome, more often in FireFox, but it's all intermittent.

**Code if needed (also available in JS Bin):**

```
        var myInterval = null;
        var container = [];
        var i, j;
        var set = false;
        var firstLetter, lastLetter;

        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#textBox").focus();
            $(document).click(function() {
                $("#textBox").focus();
            });
        });


        function pal (input) {
            var str = input.replace(/\s/g, '');
            var str2 = str.replace(/\W/g, '');

            if (checkPal(str2, 0, str2.length-1)) {
                $("#textBox").css({"color" : "green"});
                $("#response").html(input + " is a palindrome");
                $("#palindromeRun").html(input);
                $("#palindromeRun").lettering();
                if (set === false) {
                    callback(str2);
                    set = true;
                }
            }
            else {
                $("#textBox").css({"color" : "red"});
                $("#response").html(input + " is not a palindrome");
            }
            if (input.length <= 0) {
                $("#response").html("");
                $("#textBox").css({"color" : "black"});
            }

        }

        function checkPal (input, i, j) {
            if (input.length <= 1) {
                return false;
            }
            if (i === j || ((j-i) == 1 && input.charAt(i) === input.charAt(j))) {
                return true;
            }
            else {
                if (input.charAt(i).toLowerCase() === input.charAt(j).toLowerCase()) {
                    return checkPal(input, ++i, --j);
                }
                else {
                    return false;
                }
            }       
        }

        function callback(input) {
            $("#palindromeRun span").each(function (i, v) {
                container.push(v);
            });
            i = 0;
            j = container.length - 1;

            myInterval = setInterval(function () {
                if (i === j || ((j-i) === 1 && input.charAt(i) === input.charAt(j))) {
                    set = false;
                    window.clearInterval(myInterval);
                    container = [];
                }
                console.log(i + ' : ' + j);
                $(container[i]).css({"color": "green"});
                $(container[j]).css({"color": "green"});
                i++; 
                j--;    
            }, 1000);
        }
```

**HTML:**

```
    <input type="text" id="textBox" onkeyup="pal(this.value);"  value="" />
    <div id="response"></div>       
    <hr>
    <div id="palindromeRun"></div>
```

**I directly pasted the jsLettering code in the JSBin, but here is the CDN if needed:**

`<script src="http://letteringjs.com/js/jquery.lettering-0.6.1.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Please share your code here so that future visitors to SO can bask in all of its well-preserved, indented glory.

Comment: Entire word turns green as u type when it's a palindrome - this always work. Is this not intended effect?

Comment: The issue occurs here: http://jsbin.com/huqudolu/13/edit

Comment: @YuriyGalanter I mean eventually, yes... but not all at once. Please see above.

Comment: @BuddhistBeast correct. that's where the issue is happening and can be seen

Comment: It seems like an extremely rare occurrence... that's interesting. As a note, if I type the word "pap" and let it sit for a second, it will turn green.

Comment: I would advise naming one of your functions _callback_.

Comment: It happens when there is a word with no single middle character E.g. noon because there is a logic error in the interval. See my answer for the fix.

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
myInterval = setInterval(function () {
if (i === j) {
    set = false;
    window.clearInterval(myInterval);
    container = [];
}
console.log(i + ' : ' + j);
```

to:

```
myInterval = setInterval(function () {
if (i >= j) {//Changed to prevent infinite minus
    set = false;
    window.clearInterval(myInterval);
    container = [];
}
console.log(i + ' : ' + j);
```

[demo](http://jsbin.com/huqudolu/18/edit)